# "Syntax error near unexpected token 'then'."

Tags: bash, shell

```
while true
do
  # Subscribe to relevant topics
  mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.37 -t "0_0" -t "0_1" | while read -r topic
  do
    # This is a callback to be executed every time a client subscribes to a topic
    echo "Client subscribed to ${topic}"
    
    # Check the topic and redirect the subscription
    if [[ $topic == "0_0" ]] 
then
      mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.30 -t $topic
    elif [[ $topic == "0_1" ]]
 then
      mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.25 -t $topic
    fi
  done
  sleep 10 # Wait 10 seconds until reconnection
done
```

I've tried to comment "then" by putting  "#" in both lines. after that i've received another error:
"Syntax error near unexpected token 'elif'."

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: Iam running the script throught bash shell by tyoing this comand: ./script.sh &

Comment: The file may have weird/nonprinting characters in it (or maybe a byte order mark). Try printing it with `LC_ALL=C cat -v script.sh` and see if that shows anything unexpected. BTW, you should add a shebang line (like `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: I've tried your code(LC_ALL=C cat -v script.sh), it printed exactly what was in the file script without any unexpected outputs. I included also the other line in beginning of the file and retried but nothing changed and i got the same error

Comment: The indenting on your `then` lines is odd - are you SURE those are on a separate line from the associated `if/elif`s and not just on the same line but separated from them by as many spaces as it takes for it to LOOK like it's on a new line? Regarding `I've tried to comment "then" by putting "#" in both lines.` - don't do that, the `then`s need to be present.

Comment: In the future, please check your code at https://shellcheck.net (be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` or other as appropriate). Fix any issues, if your code is still not working, then post a question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the `then` keyword is not on the same line as the `if` statement or is separated from it by a `;`, this is working for me without error !

```
while true
do
  # Subscribe to relevant topics
  mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.37 -t "0_0" -t "0_1" | while read -r topic
  do
    # This is a callback to be executed every time a client subscribes to a topic
    echo "Client subscribed to ${topic}"
    
    # Check the topic and redirect the subscription
    if [[ $topic == "0_0" ]]; then
      mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.30 -t $topic
    elif [[ $topic == "0_1" ]]; then
      mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.25 -t $topic
    fi
  done
  sleep 10 # Wait 10 seconds until reconnection
done
```

Comment: This is definitely better / more conventional form. That said, a newline conditionally acts as a command separator if it's in a place where it's legal to have one, so the OP's original code should have worked too.